# Java Binary Search Tree incorrectly removes root?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm using a remove method that calls on a recursive helper method. When running this through my professor's tester, it said the root returned the incorrect address when removing the root with a full 3-level tree, and then an exception occurred when attempting to remove the rest of the right subtree. Testing this scenario on my own didn't yield the same results.

find(x) returns the node containing x, addToPool adds a deleted node to a node pool for later use, and tempRemove is false before remove is called. And min returns the node containing the minimum value of the given subtree. As far as I know, these should work properly.

When removing a node with two children, we were told to replace the node with the node containing the minimum value of its right subtree.

```
public boolean remove(T x) {
    if (find(x) == null) {
        return false;
    }

    root = delete(x, root);

    if (find(x) == null) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

private BinaryNode delete(T x, BinaryNode curRoot) {
    if (curRoot == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int cmp = x.compareTo(curRoot.element);

    if (cmp < 0) {
        curRoot.left = delete(x, curRoot.left);
    }

    else if (cmp > 0) {
        curRoot.right = delete(x, curRoot.right);
    }

    else {
        if (curRoot.left == null && curRoot.right == null) // No children
        {
            if (!tempRemove) {
                addToPool(curRoot);
            }
            return null;
        }

        else if (curRoot.left != null && curRoot.right == null) // Left
                                                                // child
        {
            BinaryNode curLeft = curRoot.left;
            addToPool(curRoot);
            return curLeft;
        }

        else if (curRoot.left == null && curRoot.right != null) // Right
                                                                // child
        {
            BinaryNode curRight = curRoot.right;
            if (!tempRemove) {
                addToPool(curRoot);
            }
            return curRight;
        }

        else // Two children
        {
            BinaryNode curLeft = curRoot.left;
            BinaryNode curRight = curRoot.right;
            BinaryNode temp = min(curRoot.right, curRoot.right);
            tempRemove = true;
            remove(temp.element);
            tempRemove = false;
            addToPool(curRoot);
            curRoot = temp;
            curRoot.left = curLeft;
            if (curRoot.element != curRight.element)
                curRoot.right = curRight;
        }
    }
    return curRoot;
}
```

Comment: if (!tempRemove) {
                addToPool(curRoot);
            } Where are you setting this value?

Comment: I set it directly above this function. I found out later that it was some weird compiling error. I recompiled with the same code and found that it worked fine.